# In google cloud vision API while calling client.text_detection() getting TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'features'

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

i have used the following code inside of a function, and i am returning the responce

```
     image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
     print("vision type: %s" %vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
     feature = vision.types.Feature(type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
     print(type(feature))
     response = client.text_detection(image=image,features= 
     [{'type':str(vision.enums.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION)}], image_context= 
     {"language_hints": 
     ["en"]})

Error at this line: 
response = client.text_detection(image=image,features= 
[{'type':str(vision.enums.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION)}], image_context={"language_hints": 
["en"]})
request = dict(image=image, features=[copied_features], **kwargs)
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'features'
```

NOTE:
I have visited their documentation page, however that is outdated,and I specifically wants  to set the feature type to either "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" or "TEXT_DETECTION"

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image, image_context= 
     {"language_hints": 
     ["en"]})
```

You already have text_detection in this request, you trying to set in again.
[Example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)

Answer (score -1):

Using methods like `text_detection` or `document_text_detection` you already declare `type`.

Use `annotate_image` to declare entire request json and declare `type_` there:

```html
response = client.annotate_image(
    {
        "image": {"content": image},
        "features": [{"type_": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"}],
        "image_context": {"language_hints": ["en"]},
    }
)
```